# Google Chrome. Жёлтый эффект.

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Когда Google Chrome запоминает поля ввода, такие как логин и пароль, то фон поля ввода становится жёлтого цвета. Можно каким-либо способом устранить данный эффект?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

попробуйте

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```